# How to check if 'this' has a specific attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if the element I click (this) has a specific attribute, as a condition in the if clause.
Is it possible to do this with JavaScript or jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want to test whether an attribute exists or whether it is empty? Which attribute?

Answer (score 15):

I will give the non-jQuery answer, just for kicks and giggles.

```
this.hasAttribute("foo")
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.hasAttribute

Comment: Noting that hasAttribute is not supported by IE (<9?).

Comment: According to the link in the answer it's supported from IE8.

Comment: According to w3 it's not supported by IE < 9 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_hasattribute.asp

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira w3 is not w3schools!

Answer (score 9):

In JavaScript, anything that is `null` or `undefined` (or even an empty string) is implicitly "false" so you can do this (assuming that you were referring to a HTML attribute using jQuery):

```
if ($(this).attr('foo')) {

}
```

Also, if you need the value from the attribute you can do this:

```
var foo;
if (foo = $(this).attr('foo')) {
    // use "foo" in here
}
```

Comment: Hard to recommend either of those. jQuery munges attribuets and properties so if the OP specifically wants the HTML attribute, getAttribute should be used. In the first bit of code: if (this.foo) is simpler and more efficient. In the second, don't do the assignment in the condition when the obvious place is when declaring the variable.

var foo = this.foo;
if (foo) { ... }

Comment: should be checked if === 'undefined' because the attribute could well be existed and it can be an empty string

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?\

```
if ($.trim($(this).attr('attribute')) != '') 
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are after an HTML attribute, then getAttribute is the only reasonably reliable way to go, noting that it has quirks in IE.

If you are just after a DOM property, then simply:

```
  if (this.foo) {
    ...
  }
```

will probably do. The test returns false if foo is set to the number zero (0), empty string, null, NaN or undefined. So it doesn't actually tell you if the element has that property, only that attempting to access it returns a falsey value. But that is usually sufficient.